# Is there a limit to how many points to scatter in plt.scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[A sample of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb8Di.png)

I am working on a clustering project. When I have finished clustering I wanted to visualize the data using python's `plt.scatter()`. However, I am not getting the entire points being drawn. The total number of points I expected is around 9000. However, I am getting around 20 only.

My question is there a limit to the number of points I can lay out using `plt.scatter`?

```
# K-Means Clustering

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('FYP.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [10]].values
Y=dataset.iloc[:, [9]].values
done = np.vstack((Y,X)).T


#Using LabelEncoder to change categorical values to numerical ones
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X=labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y=labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y[:,0])



# Using the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 1000, n_init = 10)
    kmeans.fit(done)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()

# Fitting K-Means to the dataset
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 1000, n_init = 10)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(done)

# Visualising the clusters
plt.scatter(done[y_kmeans == 0, 0], done[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 100, c = 'red', label = 'Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(done[y_kmeans == 1, 0], done[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 100, c = 'blue', label = 'Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(done[y_kmeans == 2, 0], done[y_kmeans == 2, 1], s = 100, c = 'green', label = 'Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s = 300, c = 'yellow', label = 'Centroids')
plt.title('Clusters of customers')
plt.xlabel("Category")
plt.ylabel("Subcategory")
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you show the first few lines of FYP.csv?

Comment: There is no such limit that matters here (maybe there is some bound using 64 bit or whatever for indexing internally; not that problematic in the real-world). Your error is somewhere else.

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the dataset. But I encoded the category and subcategory features only to be used in the clustering process. The rest of the dataset is discarded for now.

Comment: are you trying to cluster string labels? because that doesn't make any sense. you may want to try one-hot-encoding, if you are doing what i think you are doing.what do you hope to accomplish by clustering this data?

Comment: @offwhitelotus yes I am. I have tried using one-hot-encoding but I was faced with the curse of dimensionality. I do not know how can I apply any dimensionality reduction method to the encoded data.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelazimAli did you try using a sparse matrix for the one-hot-encoding? that will reduce space.